# how to get filepath form request.files in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am not getting any filepath, how can I get the filepath using this code?

**Exception:**

> System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(String filename, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement)

I am getting these message in this statement:

```
System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
```

Any ideas?

```
byte[] fileData = null;

using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    GroupAttachmentPoco groupAttachment = new GroupAttachmentPoco();
    groupAttachment.FileName = file.FileName;
    groupAttachment.FileContent = fileData;
    groupAttachment.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    groupAttachment.CreatedBy = userID;
    groupAttachment.FileSize = fileData.Length;
    groupAttachment.MimeType = file.ContentType.ToString();

    string filePath = file.FileName;
    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);
    using (System.Drawing.Image thumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(80, 80, new   System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback), IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            thumbnail.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            fileData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            memoryStream.Read(fileData, 0, (int)fileData.Length);
```

And if I get filepath then further I can continue with this.

Comment: Please include the whole exception, not just what line it occurs on. This will tell us a lot more about what the issue is. Please also include the value of `filePath` at the time of the exception. Also, why don't you directly pass in `file.FileName`? Why create the `filePath` variable at all?

Comment: Assuming `file`is an `HttpPostedFile` then `FileName` reflects the name of the file on the users system, it has no meaning on the server side (and should never be trusted without sanitization/dup checks anyway) so you cannot create an image from it as it does not exist.  You have a file stream so use `Image.FromStream()`.